# show/hide characters on CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

Can someone help? I've googled it a lot and couldn't find an answer. Is there a way to show/hide non-printable characters on the CKEditor, like there is on word? I couldn't find any plugin for it :/

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no way to do it or at least it is not easy.

Now the longer version. If you are talking about the [Pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) character then it is possible to show it in CKEditor by using HTML entities `&#182;` or `&para;` but please note this character is **NOT** non-printable by any means and in order to make it non-printable you would need to write a code which handles it and this is not easy. First of all you would need write a code (can be done as CKEditor plugin) which inserts Pilcrows on `Enter` and removes them wherever data is sent to server. So far so good but since this is a normal character (from CKEditor content area POV) you would need to handle all situations in which this character can be removed while typing, styling and modifying entered text and this is next to impossible.

As an alternative you could try having a code which inserts e.g. `spans` with PilcRow as a background image. While it would be easier to handle spans than plain character you would still need to handle all situations in which this `span` should or should not be removed while typing, deleting text, styling etc. and again this is very hard to do.